# how update Android MediaStore after i move a JPG file

Tags: android, image, move, mediastore

my app move .jpg file to others folders and to get viewable in the stock gallery i have sendBroadcast ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED

```
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + 
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() )));
```

but this take much time.. i have understand (maybe) that i have to update manually with cursor/contentResolver in mediaStore directly to get this faster. can anyone help me on this? thanks..
my code actually is:

```
 Uri uri = (Uri) list.get(cont); 
 Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, proj, null, null, null);
 int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
 cursor.moveToFirst();
 String app = cursor.getString(column_index);
 File orig =  new File( app.toString());
 File dest = new File( destination_path +"/"+ orig.getName().toString());
 orig.renameTo(dest);
```

with this i move a file from a path to another one.

after this, to get images in gallery
i have to sendBroadcast ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED

Answer (score 4):

I just had to do the same, use following to update the `MediaStore`:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, newPath);
boolean successMediaStore = context.getContentResolver().update(
    MediaStore.<TYPE>.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values,
    MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "='" + oldPath + "'", null) == 1;
```

Replace `<TYPE>` with the correct media store... (`Images`, `Video`, `Audio`...)

Comment: Use this method, instead of MediaScannerConnection, if you need immediate results.

Comment: Used this method to update Media Store when renaming a video file in Android 10. It works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MediaScannerConnection to update the OS:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
          new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
          new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
      public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
          // code to execute when scanning is complete
      }
 });
```

Comment: file is the new file created? i have tried yet this code... but in gallery i have new photos (correctly) and grey-images with old path folder as folder name... like older jpg files doesn't auto-delete from mediastore....

Comment: Yeah "file" would be "dest" in your case. AFIAK, the only reliable way to updated deleted files is via the slower media mounted broadcast.